# Augmented dickey fuller test

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

Why augmented dickey fuller test gives me less p-value i.e. less than 0.05 despite of having seasonality my data.

My data's plot:

[image]

Code for adf test :

from pandas import Series
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

```
X = nottemts
result = adfuller(X)
print('ADF Statistic: %f' % result[0])
print('p-value: %f' % result[1])
print('Critical Values:')
for key, value in result[4].items():
    print('\t%s: %.3f' % (key, value))
```

The output I get is,

ADF Statistic: -3.240917
**p-value: 0.017735**
Critical Values:
    1%: -3.460
    5%: -2.874
    10%: -2.574

This test is used to check the stationarity i.e. Mean, Variance, autocorrelation structure(Seasonality) doesnot vary with time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The dicky-fuller test is used to test if time series is stationary. Which based on your graph, just might be.

Comment: But it has seasonality present in it i.e. the autocorrelation changes over time. Right ?
Hence I guess it is Non-Stationary Series.

Comment: Yes, you are right by definition, series should not be considered stationary. There is a concept of Cyclostationary which seems to fit your series. See this related post.

Comment: Can you please provide the related post.

Comment: Yes - - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131092/does-a-seasonal-time-series-imply-a-stationary-or-a-non-stationary-time-series